# Magento 2 : How to use Default Menu in Mobile view?

Tags: magento2, mobile-menu

I would like to use My **IBNAB MegaMenu** in desktop view but, In Mobile view would like to use default Luma Menu.

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: could you please elaborate your question? are you using any theme?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI Yes, I am using a custom theme, developed using the default Magento theme. And for menu i am using the IBNAB MegaMenu But it's not working properly in mobile view, so can i use the default magento menu in responsive mode and the IBNAB menu in desktop view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution, I am calling the default menu by the following code using it in template file of the module.

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Now I just need to figure out some jquery stuff so that both the menus do not conflict with each other.

Comment: Yes that can be used to achieve your stuff & to stop the conflicts you can simply use media query

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI thanks for the suggestion, doing the same.

Comment: Okay! Welcome @JaykumarBhojwani to the MSE 1+ from me to both your question & answer feel free to ask any help over here!